# Imprimir Json en internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject, internet-explorer-11

Estoy trabajando con una Api que me devuelve un json y quiero imprimir sus valores formateados(sin llaves, corchetes, comillas, etc). Utilizo Internet Explorer ya que las herramientas de mi empresa están todas homologadas en él.

Mi código es el siguiente

```
function decodificar(jsonString) {
var jString = JSON.parse(jsonString);

/*
    El parámetro jsonString es el Json retornado por la Api.

    Al comprobar el tipo de datos del response de la Api retorna "String"
    alert(typeof(jsonString));
*/


Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jString).forEach(function(val) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = val + ' ' + jString[val];
});
```

}

Valor obtenido al imprimir:

> data [object Object],[object Object]

Suponiendo que el response de la api es el siguiente:

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","name":"fkorol","detected-in-release":{"fecha":"1/1/2018","status":"acepted"}]}
```

Valor esperado al imprimir:

```
id 1
name fkorol
detected-in-release fecha 1/1/2018
status acepted
```

Nota: el response es enorme y tiene muchas propiedades y valores, el anterior fue solo a modo de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos teniendo en cuenta tu ejemplo puedes hacer algo asi:

```js
dataApi = {"data":
[
  {"id":"1","name":"fkorol","detected-in-release":
  {"fecha":"1/1/2018","status":"acepted"}
  }
]
}
//accedo al objeto data
dataReal = dataApi.data;
//recorro la data obtenida mediante un for
for(i=0; i<dataReal.length;i++){
  //muestra toda la data por consola
  console.log(dataReal[i]);
 tempData = dataReal[i]
  document.write('ID: {'+tempData.id+'}');
  document.write('NAME: {'+tempData.name+'}');
  
}
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Funcionó a medias, el problema está en que en el código que usted puso para imprimir en el documento utiliza a "tempData.id" ó "tempData.name". En el response que devuelve la Api tiene muchas propiedades diferentes y que son hasta difícil de ponerlas a todas a la hora de imprimir, no abra alguna forma de recorrer todas las propiedades diatónicamente?